# What defines a size of CollectionViewCell inside a TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm implementing `UITableView` that contains `UICollectionView` inside. Of course, my `UITableViewCell` has a `UICollectionView`, but the problem is I don't know how to configure the height of the `UICollectionViewCell`. I tried to set height constraint to view inside my `UICollectionViewCell`, but it does not affect. There are many ways to play with size:

- Handle size of `UITableViewCell`
- Set height constraint to `UICollectionView` inside `UITableViewCell`
- Use method of `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`
- Set height constraint to view inside `UICollectionViewCell` (my method)

The last way is the most appropriate for me, but I want to know why it does not work. Here is the configuration of `UICollectionView`:

```
lazy var booksCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    var booksCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: contentView.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    booksCollectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
    booksCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return booksCollectionView
}()
```

Constraints:

```
booksCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    booksCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    booksCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    booksCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

Cell inside `UICollectionView` contains only `UIView`:

```
bookView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bookView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    bookView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bookView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 440).isActive = true
```

Changing the height of the `bookView` does not affect at all. Why that happens? How should I handle the height for `UICollectionViewCell`?

Answer (score 1):

Conform to protocol:`UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`  and implement the following method:
`collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`

Comment: This method is called when I set height constraint to UICollectionView. But in code above, I don't set it. Without setting height constraint, this method is not called, thus, there is no cells in UICollectionView. The question is why this happens? What is the best way to define height in cells of UICollectionView?

Comment: You don't have to set height constraint for using the delegate method. If you're confirming to protocol:UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, the code will call this method, irrespective of that